# Giving error when sending props in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-typescript

I am trying to send some props to my another component but it is giving this error:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please give a [mre], don't post _pictures_ of _text_.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Additionally, the error implies that the `<AddToCart>` component is not expecting this `book` prop.  We know nothing of this component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not declaring `AddToCart`'s props properly (no pun intended).

Your code should look something like this:

```ts
type Book = {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  description: string;
};

type CartProps = {
  book: Book;
};

//    btw: components (and their names) should represent *things* not actions
const AddToCart = ({ book }: CartProps) => {
//    ^^^^^^^^^
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{book.title}</h1>
      <h2>{book.author}</h2>
      <p>{book.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const book = {
    title: "Some Title",
    author: "John Smith",
    description: "Book description."
  };

  return <AddToCart book={book} />;
}
```

Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-hooks-ktyg63?file=/src/App.tsx).

---

#### Aside

Reserve “verb” names for methods/functions, not components. Component names should represent *entities* (for the most part, ex: `Cart`), not *actions* (ex: `AddToCart`).

Comment: We can use directly write this { book }: Book
Why write this { book }: CartProps

Comment: @ZebraCoder If I'm understanding, you're asking why the object containing book is set to CartProps and not Book? Because it is not true that { book } is of type Book; it is an Object containing a Book object. The bracketed object "book" is not what CartProps is type controlling; book is just one of many props that AddToCart can potentially consume (ex: { book, ASIN, timestamp }). This example was written assuming a general cart system; as in one that will include more keys in CartProps.

Comment: @ZebraCoder you can try it out in the answer's codesandbox above for clarification. If you try to set it to Book it will throw typing errors for this reason.